# How to set up Babel in NetBeans IDE?

Tags: netbeans, plugins, babeljs

Is there any plugin or way to configure Babel in my NetBeans IDE so that all files with a `.js` extension would be automatically compiled into ES5, similarly like SASS preprocessor automatically (on save) compiles `.scss` into `.css` files?

Answer (score 0):

Add `devDependencies` and `scripts` to your `package.json` file as shown below and then run `npm install` **or** add just `scripts` to your `package.json` file as shown below and install babel locally with `npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env`.

```
{
  "name": "some-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "some_author",
  "contributors": [],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.1.8"
  },
  "scripts":{
    "ES6 -> ES5": "babel public/js/es6 --watch --presets babel-preset-env --out-dir public/js"
  }
}
```

Then just right click on your project in NetBeans **Projects** window, select `npm scripts` and select `ES6 -> ES5`. This will compile all files **on save** in `public/js/es6` directory into `public/js` directory

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42306463/2) to the question [How to set up Babel in NetBeans IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42306463/how-to-set-up-babel-in-netbeans-ide/74685602) by the OP [Paweł](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5388390/pawe%c5%82) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>